# Ubuntu grub menu doesn't appear after installing windows 10

Tags: windows

I had Ubuntu 20.04 LTS installed on my computer and then I installed `Windows 10` so that I can dual-boot with `Ubuntu` but now when I start my computer, the `grub menu` doesn't appear anymore and it automatically launches `Windows 10`. I tried to see how to fix it but it didn't work. This command `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi` didn't work for me.
And in the `Windows` `disk management`, the partitions are like this

This is a screenshot.

[image]

As you can see, the first partition is for `Windows` and the second is for `Ubuntu`, it shows that the free space is 100%. Does that mean that `Ubuntu` was deleted ?

Comment: Windows does not see Linux partitions, so your screen shot does not tell us anything. And with BIOS installs on MBR(msdos) systems, Windows has a bug (they may call it a feature) that deletes unknown logical partitions. Show this from Ubuntu live installer: `sudo parted -l`. Windows 8 or 10 are not dual boot friendly in BIOS/MBR configuration, better with UEFI/gpt.

Comment: I also stopped doing dual-boots after I found that some windows 10 updates caused issues with Ubuntu installations, because as @oldfred noted, sometimes Windows felt empowered to change the partitions on my disk

Comment: Have you tried running `boot-repair`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem like this (`Ubuntu` was not deleted):

- I installed `grub2` on a usb following those steps [here](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/install-grub2-on-usb-from-windows/)
- I restarted my computer and pressed `F9` to enter into the boot menu
- I selected "Boot from usb" then the `grub Terminal` appeared
- Enter the following commands to start `Ubuntu`
  `ls -l` to see where `Ubuntu` is `(hd1,msdos5)` for my case
  `set root=(hd1,5)`
  `linux /boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-44-generic root=/dev/sda5` you can press `tab` after `linux /boot/` to complete the command
  `initrd /boot/initrd.img-5.8.0-44-generic`
  `boot`
- This will start `Ubuntu`
- Once in `Ubuntu` , I used `Boot Repair` to fix the problem,
  `sudo apt install software-properties-common; \ sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe"; \ sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair; \ sudo apt-get update; \ sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair` .